# Getting syntax error while using 'source /some/path/to/file' inside a sudoers file

Tags: bash, shell, sudoers

I have a user 'abc' to whom I want to give very limited permissions. One of them is 'abc' must be able to source a file but not read it. So, I made root the owner of this file & am trying to give sudo access to this 'abc' user so that he can source it.

```
abc ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: source /file/path
```

When I write the above to /etc/sudoers file I get syntax error.

I got to know that 'source' is a build-in function & not a program which can be used in sudoers file. If so, then is there any other way out for my problem?

Comment: "*must be able to source a file but not read it*" does not make sense, you must have read access to be able to source a file.  Please show the *exact* error message and the circumstances that you get the error.  "*When I write the above to /etc/sudoers file I get syntax error*" is ambiguous, how are you writing it?

Comment: I am writing it using visudo. The error i get is,
/etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 116

Comment: `must beable to source a file but not read it` This is impossible. `source` is bash builtin, can' t be passed to sudo. You can create a wrapper that on execution will output the file in question.

Comment: @AbhishekSharmaM : You could specify the command as, i.e., `/bin/bash -c "source /file/path"`, though I don't understand why you don't simply run the script without using the `source` builtin, but of course this is up to you to decided. However, I don't think that this will YOUR error disappear, because you said that you get a *syntax* error on the sudoers file, and this means that sudo doesn't even try to invoke your (erroneous) _source_ command. Since the line you posted, is not syntactically wrong, the error must be somewhere else. Check for instance the line endings of the file.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a file (here, I will call it `the_sourcerer.sh`) with the source command

```
#!/bin/bash    
source /file/path
```

Make sure you run the following before trying to use it

```
chmod +x /path/to/the_sourcerer.sh
```

Then add the corrected line to `/etc/sudoers`

```
abc ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /path/to/the_sourcerer.sh
```